# Error: Assigning to char* from incompatible type void*

Tags: c++, g++

So I'm trying to store a response from a libcURL HTTP request into a C-string to be parsed later on. The response code is written entirely in C, while everything else is in C++, and with any other C++ compiler, it should work fine. But when I try to compile, even if I give the '-x c' arguments followed by the filename, I get these specific responses.

```
g++ main.cpp -x c cJSON.c -x c respbuffer.c -lcurl -lm

./respbuffer.c:14:9: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'
    s->ptr = malloc(s->len+1);
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./respbuffer.c:23:9: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'
    s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, new_len+1);
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Weirdly enough, this error only pops up when compiling with g++. If I use gcc, it works fine, and it runs smoothly enough. For the curious, I wrote everything in Xcode, and I'm compiling with GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: In C, this would be fine... but in C++ you need to cast to the correct pointer type.

Comment: Possibly you should compile your C sources separately from your C++ and then link the object files afterward.

Comment: It's not common to compile multiple source files in a single invocation of the compiler, especially when they're in multiple languages. I think most people would compile your files with four commands: One for g++ to compile the C++ code, two for gcc to compile the C files, and finally, one more invocation of g++ to link the three object files with the libraries and produce an executable.

Comment: You could try leaving out the `-x c` parts to let the compiler choose based on the file extension... or maybe `gcc -c cJSON.c respbuffer.c` then `g++ main.cpp cJSON.o respbuffer.o  -lcurl -lm`

Comment: Dmitri, I tried it your way and I still got the same error. It is probably an issue with the incorrect type being cast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because C is pretty laxed with types, while C++ is strict. malloc() returns void*, so in order to use it as char* you need to cast it.

Comment: But why is it being compiled as C++ in the first place? Shouldn't the `-x c` option ensure it's compiled as C? I think *that's* the key to this question, but you haven't addressed it.

Comment: I think, g++ got confused since first file is cpp. I am no expert in g++ command line switches, though. I would suggest to stop compiling and linking in a single command, and just compile every file individually, than link them together. This will remove all need for special switches.

Comment: I casted it with a (char*) and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use a C++ compiler to compile C code. The two languages are different, and code which is correct in C may silently misbehave in C++.

Adding a cast to your code masks the problem; even if it appears to work for now, you really have no idea what else might be happening.

On my system, `-x c` causes `g++` to actually invoke the C compiler.  Perhaps you have some version of g++ that does not support that switch, or perhaps `g++` is an alias for some other compiler on your system.

If you cannot get `-x c` to work, then use `gcc` as the compiler instead of `g++` .  (You will need to use separate invocations for the C files than for the C++ files, followed by a link step).

Comment: If I compile the C files with `gcc`, then use `g++` to compile `main.cpp` and the  `.o` files from the `gcc` compilation, would that work?

Comment: @hudspero yes, that should work... I suggested that in a comment yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

In C the `malloc` function return a `void*` of a memory block on the heap. In C it's everything ok because a `void*` is implicitly casted to a `char*`.
But in C++ it's forbidden, so you have to explicitly cast it.

So in this case the right code is:

```
s->ptr = static_cast<char*>(malloc(s->len+1));
```

Comment: But the `-x c` options on the command line are supposed to tell the compiler to treat the file as C, right? I think any answer to this question needs to address the command-line options, not simply the language differences between C and C++.